# Flutter - custom fontStyle not working after adding ThemeData

Tags: flutter, text, styles

I have been using custom `TextStyle` and have saved my font files in myApp/fonts/ and they were working well.

However, after I have added `ThemeData` to my App, the custom `TextStyle` are not working, they seem to look to have some additional `weight`. I am using the same text font for my custom `TextStyle` and `ThemeData`, the only differences were the font sizes. I also need to use custom `TextStyle` as I have more font sizes needed than the preset 5 headlines and 2 subtitles and 2 bodyTexts `ThemeData` provide.

Does anyone have any idea please?

pubspec:

```
flutter:
  fonts:
     - family: Baskerville
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Baskerville.ttc
     - family: Futura
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Futura.ttc
     - family: Tinos
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/Tinos-Italic.ttf
           style: italic
         - asset: fonts/Tinos-BoldItalic.ttf
           weight: 700
  uses-material-design: true
```

My ThemeData:

```
class MyPortfolio extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.grey[900],
        accentColor: Colors.grey[900],
        fontFamily: 'Futura',
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 48),
          headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          headline3:
              TextStyle(fontSize: 40, decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
          headline4: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          headline5: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
          subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
          subtitle2: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, fontFamily: 'Baskerville'),
          bodyText1: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontFamily: 'Tinos',
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              color: Colors.grey),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontFamily: 'Tinos',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              color: Colors.grey),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My code:

```
class IntroSection extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      ...
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                              text: 'People say xxx is ',
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: '...',
                                    style:
                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3)),
                                ...
                Container(
                  child: Text.rich(
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'And I am actually an ',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Futura',
                          fontSize: 40,
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(40, 46, 49, 100)),
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                            text: 'artist-designer ',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Futura',
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic)),
                        ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts Or maybe share some more code on how you're implementing your font in your app.

Comment: Hi @Er1 I have added more code :)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having issues. Have you tried `flutter clean`? Maybe go step by step by only setting `fontFamily` in your themeData to see if that works, and expand from there.